# NodeJS express - How to add session data inside router?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I need to add some session data express router (using express-session and passport).

I store the data correctly into user record in DB (mongo) and try to set the value to session data:

```
req.user.myData = "my session data";
```

Unfortunately the user data are serialized only during user authorization via passport. So "myData" are not stored into current session. When new user session is started, data are loaded from DB correctly and are available.

Is there any way (I expect so) to make data available in current session?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `req.session.myData`? You put data into the session by adding properties to the session object and then saving the session.  That property will then be part of a future request's session object.

Answer (score 0):

Most such things in ExpressJS world done using middlewares:

1) create js file in `middlewares` folder: `populateUserData.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.user) req.user = {};
  req.user.someData = 'something';

  next();
}
```

2.1) attach it after passport:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(require('./middlewares/populateUserData'));
```

or

2.2) attach it to specific route:

```
const populateUserData = require('./middlewares/populateUserData');

route.get('/api/users/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  populateUserData,
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({ id: req.user.id, username: req.user.username });
  });
```

or

2.3) in group of routes:

```
app.use('/api/users',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  require('./middlewares/populateUserData'),
  require('./routes/api/users'));
```

also You can create Your own middlewares that would be helpful,

for example: https://github.com/num8er/alttab-nodejs-challenge/blob/master/app.js#L19

Comment: Thx for your answer. It helps me in other cases.

But in my original case does not. It is quite application/route specific. I was able to do little workaround. 

Instead of storing to user data, I store directly to session data:

    req.session.myData;

And then check both, user and session data:

    `var myData = req.user.myData;
    if(req.session.myData) {
        myData = req.session.myData;
    }`

Comment: if You want use it in application route, check my updated answer, as I said "most such things done using middlewares, cuz express itself is middleware based framework. docs: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html  You can chain how many middlewares You want.

Comment: That is exactly what I need.

Comment: yaaaay! (: happy to be helpful